# How to add TextBox or DropDownList to a ASP.NET TreeView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I am trying to add a TextBox or DropDownList to the nodes in a standard ASP.NET TreeView control so that I can take the user input when the node is selected and make use of the input text on postback in the code behind.  The TreeView is configured to show CheckBoxes.

If this is not possible, is there a way to render a text close to the node when it is selected for taking input? Or maybe have a Javascript prompt to take input when node is selected?

Comment: You do realize that a tree view is just a <ul> in html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry to inform you but there is just no way for a TreeView to store other controls. If you wish to have such a functionality you will have to write your own TreeView.

As for TreeView usage in Windows Forms - here is [a simplistic example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tree/DropDownTreeView.aspx)